# Can the crank be removed from a 1999 beetle without engine removal

Tags: engine, vw, beetle

Spun the rod bearing. I dropped the oil pan and found the affected rod. I disconnected the rod. If I can remove it and have the journal turned or replace it, it would be more work but less money than to replace the engine. I don't have access to a lift. I was thinking of disassembling the engine in the car to get to the block. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly get it out, but putting it back in would be nearly impossible. To do it correctly, you should put new bearings throughout (rods & mains). Putting new main bearings in requires checking clearances. You would not be able to do this by having the crank hang on the bearing caps.

Since you spun a bearing, the engine block should be thoroughly cleaned as well. When the bearing spun, metal from the journal side and from the rod side was strewn all over the engine.

I'm still not sure how you would disconnect the crank from the flywheel (or flex plate if an auto).

One other thing to think about is if you are unsure what caused the spun bearing in the first place, it could easily happen again. If it was over revving the engine, which caused a rod bolt to stretch, thus causing the spun bearing, that's one thing. If it was a lack of lubrication, that's another.

While I have never tried this myself, this seems like about a 1:1,000,000 shot to make it happen and have the fix work for any length of time.